# Strange behavior of wrapfigure and description list

Tags: lists, wrapfigure, description, wrap

Not sure exactly how to describe this. Here's what the pdf looks like:

[image]

Immediately after figure 4.6, the text correctly returns to full lines. But then with the next item in the `description` list, the text acts as though it still needs to wrap around the figure.

Providing an MWE for this is a bit complicated, as this behavior only shows up when things are "just so," but here's my code for the figure and the list:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{R}{0.4\textwidth}
    \captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{Figures/VIcurves}
    \rule{.4\textwidth}{.4pt}
    \caption[Example V-I curve for solar PV panel]{Example V-I curve for solar PV panel \cite{solarex_millenia_1999}.}
    \label{fig:VIcurves}
\end{wrapfigure}

Blah blah blah

\subsubsection{Inverters}

Blah blah blah

\begin{description}
    \item[UPS inverters] use mains power to charge a battery bank, and supply ac loads with power from the batteries when mains power is not avaialable. Three 700 \si{VA} UPS inverters are in use at CREST.
    \item[Solar UPS inverters] use solar PV input to charge the batteries and supply loads, when available. One 2400 \si{VA} solar UPS inverter is in use at CREST.
\end{description}
```

Comment: Reading the `wrapfig` manual on the first page: `You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or or immediately
before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a list if there is a blank line
(\par) in between.` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer then it seems "immediately" is relative - I edited my code snippet to reflect the fact that there is a paragraph, a new section start, and a second paragraph, between the figure and the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can interrupt and resume the description environment, emulating a vertical spacing of `\itemsep` between the two environments:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{wrapfig, siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{graphicx}%[demo]
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum, calc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\setcounter{section}{4}
\setcounter{subsection}{4}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{1}

\begin{wrapfigure}[17]{R}{0.4\textwidth}
    \captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{hare-blazon}
    \rule{.4\textwidth}{.4pt}
    \caption[Example V-I curve for solar PV panel]{Example V-I curve for solar PV panel \cite{solarex_millenia_1999}.}
    \label{fig:VIcurves}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[5]

\subsubsection{Inverters}

Blah blah blah

\begin{description}
    \item[UPS inverters] use mains power to charge a battery bank, and supply ac loads with power from the batteries when mains power is not available. Three 700 \si{VA} UPS inverters are in use at CREST.
\end{description}
\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\topsep + 2\partopsep + \baselineskip -\itemsep}
\begin{description}
    \item[Solar UPS inverters] use solar PV input to charge the batteries and supply loads, when available. One 2400 \si{VA} solar UPS inverter is in use at CREST.
    \item[UPS inverters] use mains power to charge a battery bank, and supply ac loads with power from the batteries when mains power is not available. Three 700 \si{VA} UPS inverters are in use at CREST.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, but this seems like a bug to me.

Comment: What is a bug? What happens without this trick? It's known `wrapfig` and all similar packages are not really compatible with lists environments. You can try  using the `insbox` plain TeX macro package, but won't float, and you'll have to use `\captionof{figure}{…}`.